# How do I get 0-padded numbers in {} (brace expansion)?

Tags: bash, scripting, for

I'm trying to write a simple script to retrieve memory and swap usage from a list of hosts. Currently, the only way I've been able to achieve this is to write 3 separate scripts:

```
for a in {1..9}; do echo "bvrprdsve00$a; $(ssh -q bvrprdsve00$a "echo \$(free -m|grep Mem|/bin/awk '{print \$4}';free -m|grep Swap|/bin/awk '{print \$4}')")"; done > /tmp/svemem.txt;
for a in {10..99}; do echo "bvrprdsve0$a; $(ssh -q bvrprdsve0$a "echo \$(free -m|grep Mem|/bin/awk '{print \$4}';free -m|grep Swap|/bin/awk '{print \$4}')")"; done >> /tmp/svemem.txt;
for a in {100..218}; do echo "bvrprdsve$a; $(ssh -q bvrprdsve$a "echo \$(free -m|grep Mem|/bin/awk '{print \$4}';free -m|grep Swap|/bin/awk '{print \$4}')")"; done >> /tmp/svemem.txt
```

The reason for this is that the hostname always ends in a 3 digit number and these hosts go from 001-218, so I've needed to do a different `for` loop for each set (001-009, 010-099, 100-218). Is there a way in which I can do this in one script instead of joining 3 together?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Bash brace expansions could generate the numbers with leading zeros ([since bash 4.0 alpha+ ~2009-02-20](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges)):

```
$ echo {001..023}
001 002 003 004 005 006 007 008 009 010 011 012 013 014 015 016 017 018 019 020 021 022 023
```

So, you can do:

```
for a in {001..218}; do  echo "bvrprdsve$a; $(ssh -q bvrprdsve$a "echo \$(free -m|grep Mem|/bin/awk '{print \$4}';free -m|grep Swap|/bin/awk '{print \$4}')")"; done >> /tmp/svemem.txt
```

But, let's look inside the command a little bit:

1. You are calling free twice, using grep and then awk:

   ```
   free -m|grep Mem |/bin/awk '{print \$4}';
   free -m|grep Swap|/bin/awk '{print \$4}'
   ```

   All could be reduced to this one call to `free` and `awk`:

   ```
   free -m|/bin/awk '/Mem|Swap/{print \$4}'
   ```
2. Furthermore, the internal command could be reduced to this value:

   ```
   cmd="echo \$(free -m|/bin/awk '/Mem|Swap/{print \$4}')"
   ```

Then, the whole script will look like this:

```
b=bvrprdsve;
f=/tmp/svemem.txt;
cmd="echo \$(free -m|/bin/awk '/Mem|Swap/{print \$4}')";
for a in {001..218}; do echo "$b$a; $(ssh -q "$b$a" "$cmd")"; done >> "$f";
```

Comment: Or use `for ...; do echo "$b$a"; ssh -q "$b$a" free -m | awk '/Mem|Swap/ {print $4}; done >"$f"` There is no use running `awk` remotely. If the `echo` is for nothing more than eye candy, just put the `awk` after the loop: `for ...; do ssh "$b$a" free -m; done | awk '/Mem|Swap/{print \$4}') >"$f"`.  Or use Ansible.

Answer (score 9):

`printf '%04d' "$a"` will output a zero-filled four digit string if `$a` is an integer.

Example:

```
a=14
printf -v b '%04d' "$a"

printf '%s\n' "$b"
```

will output

```
0014
```

So just loop as before and create your zero-filled variable and use that:

```
for a in {1..9}; do
  printf -v za '%04d' "$a"
  # rest of code, using $za
done
```

The assignment to `za` above could also be done with

```
printf -v za '%04d' "$a"   # print to variable za
```

To be more readable to the C programmer

```
for (( a = 1; a < 10; ++a )); do
  printf -v za '%04d' "$a"
  # rest of code, using $za
done
```

I haven't looked at the rest of the code.

Note: In `ksh` one may set an attribute on a variable so that its expansion is always zero-filled:

```
typeset -Z4 za
for (( a = 1; a < 10; ++a )); do
  za="$a"
  printf "%s\n" "$za"
done

0001
0002
0003
0004
0005
0006
0007
0008
0009
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use `seq -w 1 218` or `seq -f "%03g" 1 218` to generate your numbers.

Answer (score 5):

Although [Brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) has a zero-padding method, I found [Parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) more useful to alter existing variable:

```
digits=00000
num=123

# Option 1:
temp=$digits$num
echo ${temp:(-${#digits})}
# prints 00123

# Option 2:
echo ${digits:${#num}:${#digits}}${num}
# prints 00123
```